# Очень быстрая передача данных между устройствами

Tags: java, android

Делаю один проект, суть в чем:

Есть 2 android-смартфона.

Нужно между ними, по интернету (3G) очень быстро передать какие-то данные (3-5 символов, к примеру)

Как мне это сделать? Скорость интернета где-то 30-40 кб/с (в худших случаях, обычно около 150-ти).

Нужно что-то, что способно передать эти 5 символов с пингом меньше 100 м/c.

Какой сервис посоветуете? Я смотрю в сторону firebase, но он достаточно медленный.

Comment: Меньше 100 мс сделать на 3G вам никакой сервис не поможет.
https://serverfault.com/questions/387627/why-do-mobile-networks-have-high-latencies-how-can-they-be-reduced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавайте свои данные по протоколу UDP. В отличии от протокола TCP он не тратит время на установку соединения и на проверку доставленных данных. Но будте готовы к тому, что пакет с вашими 3-5 символами не дойдёт до адресата или будет получен несколько раз вместо одного. То есть вам придётся взять часть функциональности TCP на себя.